# Azure DevOps SDK (not API) - getting releases for a build

Tags: azure-devops, azure-rest-api

I'm writing a web app that makes use of the .NET SDK packages for Azure DevOps. I'm  displaying changesets (TFS only currently) from a specific team's iteration. I look into the tasks and check for changesets and linked builds.Then I check the status of those builds and display whether the build was successful.

My problem is finding the releases related to each individual build. If you go to a build in your organization, there's a Release tab that shows the related release and the status of its stages so Microsoft are using some method/API to do that. I'm trying this with the older XAML pipelines, not YAML.

The link to view that tab I mentioned would be: "`https://dev.azure.com/organizationName/projectName/_build/results?buildId=22224&view=ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.deployments-tab`" where 22224 is the build ID.

I would like to know if there's an SDK method for that, and as a last resort, if the SDK doesn't have it, I could use the API directly.

Currently, I'm getting the build info like that:

```
build = await buildClient.GetBuildAsync(projectId, int.Parse(buildId));
```

This has a property `RetainedByRelease` which could be true even if a release failed and there's nothing in the build linking it to a Release. If I go looking into the releases first and filtering them by the Artifacts (using the build definition ID), it's not ideal because there could be multiple release pipelines using artifacts from the same build definition. Also, there could be multiple releases happening almost immediately one after the other so filtering by the FinishDate of the build doesn't work great. Sometimes a release is done manually, 1 day after the build.

Any ideas how to pinpoint the exact Release that was done from a specific build?

NuGet packages used:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client" Version="16.205.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.InteractiveClient" Version="16.205.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Release.Client" Version="16.205.1" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here's how I ended up doing it. First of all, I'd get all releases (not filtered by definition) that were done in the last 30 days and I will filter the top 100.

```
var releases = await pipelinesHttpClient2.GetReleasesAsync2(projectId, minCreatedTime: DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30),
                expand: ReleaseExpands.Artifacts | ReleaseExpands.Environments, top: 100, statusFilter: ReleaseStatus.Active);
```

I have a foreach after that where I get the build info but if you could, first get the build info and check if the build succeeded and only then look for a release. Anyway, get the build:

```
build = await buildClient.GetBuildAsync(projectId, int.Parse(buildId));
```

You can check if it succeeded or not:

```
build.Result == BuildResult.Succeeded || build.Result == BuildResult.PartiallySucceeded
```

Now using the `releases` we got earlier, we will check for releases that have an Artifact with the same Id as the build Id, and you can find that like so:

```
var releasesForBuild = releases.Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Artifacts.Where(a => a.IsPrimary)
                                    .SingleOrDefault()?.DefinitionReference["version"].Id) == build.Id);
```

Another useful property would be `DefinitionReference["version"].Name`, check it out.

The expression we wrote could return multiple releases for that Artifact but let's assume we care for one, we can use `FirstOrDefault()` to get it.

`var specificRelease = releasesForBuild.FirstOrDefault();`

Now the next point is that this release could have multiple stages, in some cases, stages you don't even care about. I haven't added filtering on the stages yet, but if you'd like to check if at least one succeeded, you could do it like so:

```
isReleasedSuccessfully = specificRelease?.Environments
                             .Any(x => x.Status == EnvironmentStatus.Succeeded || x.Status == EnvironmentStatus.PartiallySucceeded) ?? false;
```

I hope that was helpful, it took me some time.